# Swapping keys of nested maps in a list using Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have an object with structure

```
List<Map<String(k1), Map<String(k2), String(v2)>>>
```

I need to convert the above list to

```
List<Map<String(k2), Map<String(k1), String(v2)>>>
```

I am stuck on how do i get the nested map using construct like

```
serviceResults.stream().map((k, v) -> ????)
```

that will allow me to swap the keys. Is it possible to do it in a way without using loops using Java 8 streams?

**Additional Info**
This is the code that uses loop construct

```
    List<Map<String, Map<String, String>>> serviceResults = new ArrayList<>();
    //Populate the above list

    Map<String, Map<String, String>> swpMapOuter = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, String> swpMapInner = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map<String, Map<String, String>> stringMapMap : serviceResults) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>> s : stringMapMap.entrySet()) {
            String key1 = s.getKey();
            Map<String, String> value1 = s.getValue();
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> s1 : value1.entrySet()) {
                String key2 = s1.getKey();
                String value2 = s1.getValue();
                swpMapInner.put(key1, value2);
                swpMapOuter.put(key2, swpMapInner);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("swpMapOuter " + swpMapOuter);
```

Below is the code with forEach, instead of for loops, but was wondering, if it could be implemented using Stream constructs

```
    Map<String, Map<String, String>> swpMapOuter2 = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, String> swpMapInner2 = new HashMap<>();
    serviceResults.forEach((stringMapMap) -> {
        stringMapMap.entrySet().forEach((s) -> {
            String key1 = s.getKey();
            Map<String, String> value1 = s.getValue();
            value1.entrySet().forEach((s1) -> {
                String key2 = s1.getKey();
                String value2 = s1.getValue();
                swpMapInner2.put(key1, value2);
                swpMapOuter2.put(key2, swpMapInner2);
            });
        });
    });

    System.out.println("swpMapOuter2 " + swpMapOuter2);
```

Comment: Yes perhaps use `map`?

Comment: You mean stream's map, right? That is where I am stuck, unless you mean something different.

Comment: try  `List<Map<String, Map<String, String>>> result = list.stream()
                .flatMap(e -> e.entrySet().stream())
                .flatMap(e -> e.getValue()
                               .entrySet()
                               .stream()
                               .map(v -> Map.of(v.getKey(), Map.of(e.getKey(), v.getValue()))))
                .collect(toList());` 1) I've not tested it, 2) Map.of is from JDK9, 3) `Map.of` returns an immutable map. if all the aforementioned points are fine with you and the code works then you're in luck otherwise it will give you an idea....